# Roles for "Hhtpcontext.user" in Asp.net Formauthentication

Tags: asp.net-2.0

In asp.net global.asax, where should i write code to assign role in httpcontext.user?

What i have read in site is that it should be part of "Application_onPostauthentication" event of global.asax but i am not getting that if i write there then it is execute for each request of user. I think this should fetch one for one authentication at session.

I don't know even why microsoft also suggest to write code there? Please if anybody know the fact make me clear?

Answer (score 1):

With .NET 2.0 you can use [the built-in role management feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx), which handles setting roles for you.

For .NET 1.1, or if some reason you can't or don't want to use the built-in role management, then the PostAuthenticateRequest event is a good place to do it.

Session is not used to store roles because (a) the lifetime of the session is completely independent of the lifetime of the forms authenticatio cookie and (b) session may not even be enabled.

The roles do need to be set on each request, but this isn't a problem.  You don't need to retrieve them from the database (*) each time - you can cache them somewhere.  Caching them in Session is a reasonable solution, but you do need to include code to reread from the database if you don't find them there.

(*) or wherever you have stored them.

**EDIT**

For example, to cache roles in Session you could do something like:

```
string[] GetRoles(string userName)
{
    string[] roles = Session["Roles"] as string[];
    if (roles == null)
    {
       roles = GetRolesFromDatabase(userName);
       Session["Roles"] = roles;
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Alternatively you can avoid the dependency on Session by storing the roles in the ASP.NET cache, probably with a sliding expiration.  The Cache is shared between all requests, so you'd need to use the username as part of the cache key:

```
string[] GetRoles(string userName)
{
    string cacheKey = "Roles:" + userName;

    string[] roles = Cache[cacheKey] as string[];
    if (roles == null)
    {
       roles = GetRolesFromDatabase(userName);
       Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, ...);
    }
    return roles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice solution, did you have more explanation (example) for whatever you have written int the last paragraph of your reply ie. " catch roles in session is reasonable solution" 
Please if have example links so that it makes me more understand

Comment: @HemantKothiyal: Hell, why didn't you upvote and accept this answer? It's extremely useful and Joe even gave additional infos after your comment. I don't understand why you don't appreciate his effort.